# Build errors in NextJS in __webpack_require__

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am currently transferring a site from React-Fuse to NextJS with React.  Mostly everything is working fine, but upon trying to create a build there is an error that I cannot get around:

```js
> Build error occurred
TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined
```

is thrown in every build, it is coming from the `__webpack_require__` function at

```js
modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
```

`modules[moduleId]` is undefined.

I've tried every fix I can find online and nothing seems to be working, any help is appreciated

babelrc is :

```
{
    "presets": ["next/babel"]
}
```

next.config has nothing pertaining to webpack, only some redirects

Pages are written as follows:

```js
import SomePage from 'components/aPage/SomePage'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import * as AuthActions from 'auth/store/actions'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    ...
}

function mapStateToProps({ user, bank }) {
    ...
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomePage)
```

with the actual jsx file being imported and then connected to the store.

Answer (score 4):

Try to clean your ".next" folder and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 1):

Delete your .next folder and run npm install. If it gives error due to version, then run npm install --force

Answer (score 0):

just delete your `.next` build folder , `node_modules` folder and `lock.yaml` file .

Then rerun the installation script e.g: `pnpm install` ( Note :based on your package manager you use in your project) .

hope it will work.